# Django admin override model field validation

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-validation

I have a `fee` DecimalField in my model as follow:

```
class CardTypes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "card_types"
        verbose_name = 'Card Type'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Card Types'

    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    fee = models.DecimalField("Fee", max_digits=65, decimal_places=0, default=0)
    image_url = models.CharField("Image Url", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def card_type_image(self):
        if self.image_url is not None:
            return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="130" height="90" />' % (self.image_url))
        else:
            return "No image yet"
    card_type_image.short_description = 'image'

    def fee_convert(self):
        if self.fee is not None:
            currency = Currency.objects.get(pk=1)
            return Decimal(self.fee / pow(10, currency.decimals))
        else:
            return None
    fee_convert.short_description = 'Fee'
```

I set `DecimalField("Fee", max_digits=65, decimal_places=0, default=0)` because i want to save it with no decimal place on my DB, but on the admin site i want to interact with it converted method.

For excample if fee in database is 0.00005 then in the admin it will only show and save with the value of 5(because currency.decimals = 5)

I managed to show the converted value and save with the value of 5 in the admin side like so :

```
class CardTypeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CardTypeAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.fee is not None:
            try:
                self.initial['fee'] = self.instance.fee_convert()
            except:
                pass

    def clean_fee(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['fee'] is not None:
            currency = Currency.objects.get(pk=1)
            data = Decimal(self.cleaned_data['fee'] * pow(10, currency.decimals))
        else:
            data = None

        return data

class CardTypesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'card_type_image',)
    list_display_links = ('name', 'card_type_image', )

    form = CardTypeAdminForm
    fields = (
        'id',
        'name',
        'fee',
        'image_url',
        'card_type_image',
        'deleted_at',
    )

    readonly_fields = (
        'id',
        'card_type_image',
        'deleted_at'
    )

admin.site.register(CardTypes, CardTypesAdmin)
```

But in the case of i want to input the fee field in admin with value of 0.005 or with decimal place(should work because in the db it will be save as 500) , but the admin validation return the following validation error:

> Ensure that there are no more than 0 decimal places.

Because the admin form field inherit validation from model Field, is there anyway i can override it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around by creating new field in the form replace of the fee form field:

```
class CardTypeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    currency = Currency.objects.get(pk=1)
    fee = forms.DecimalField(required=False, decimal_places=currency.decimals)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CardTypeAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.fee is not None:
            try:
                self.initial['fee'] = self.instance.fee_convert()
            except:
                pass

    def clean_fee(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['fee'] is not None:
            currency = Currency.objects.get(pk=1)
            data = Decimal(self.cleaned_data['fee'] * pow(10, currency.decimals))
        else:
            data = None

        return data
    class Meta:
        model = CardTypes
        exclude = ['fee']

class CardTypesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'card_type_image',)
    list_display_links = ('name', 'card_type_image', )

    form = CardTypeAdminForm
    fields = (
        'id',
        'name',
        'fee',
        'image_url',
        'card_type_image',
        'deleted_at',
    )

    readonly_fields = (
        'id',
        'card_type_image',
        'deleted_at'
    )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.fee = form.cleaned_data['fee']
        return super(CardTypesAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```